# Style HTML textbox

Tags: html, css

How can I style my textbox like this email text box?

```
<div id="main">
    <input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Add Element" class="bt" />
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hba4cyej/) demonstrating my issue

Comment: I can't able to open image url, can you please attach the same here.

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/lh4xt446r/Invite.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add css in your html page like:

```
<style>
.input {
    color: #333333;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 250px;
}
</style>
```

Add `placeholder="Email"` in input tag which will remove when user type.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hba4cyej/1/) here.

Comment: Thanks .. but when i click add button, that time input value and text color didn't change right?

Comment: Have you check <input  type=text class="input" id="tb1"  placeholder="Email" /> here class="input" so it will set `.input` style check http://jsfiddle.net/hba4cyej/2/

Comment: Okay, I didn't add placeholder, because already they put value.. so i just modified value from Text Element to email.. is it right?

Comment: but default 4 text boxes have email as placeholder, and when i click the button, it shows text box placeholder  has Text Element 5 ,.. so how can i change to Placeholder as same email? thanks

Comment: Just remove value on click.

Comment: ` $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
                            'value="Text Element ' + iCnt + '" placeholder="Email" />');` here.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/hba4cyej/5/  ` $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + '  placeholder="Email" />');`

Answer (score 0):

try this This will show stylish textbox

```
<input type="text"class="inputs" placeholder="e-mail" /> 
 <input type="password" class="inputs"placeholder="Password" /> 
  <style> 
inputs:-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #b5b5b5;
 }
 inputs-moz-placeholder {
color: #b5b5b5;
 }

.inputs {
width: 270px;
padding: 15px 25px;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 14px;
color: #9D9E9E;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(256, 256, 256, 1.0);
background: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
 }

 .inputs:focus {
  background: #DFE9EC;
  color: #414848;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  outline: 0;
 }

 .inputs:hover {
  background: #DFE9EC;
  color: #414848;
  }
  </style>
```